# add not secure https service to proxy service wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I want to add Not secure https service (https://192.168...) to wso2 esb. import the certificate from [1] to [ESB_HOM]/resources/security/client_truststore.jks VIA

```
:\>keytool import public_cert.crt -alias myservice -keystore client_truststore.jks
```

and uncomment parameter in axis2 and change it to the following

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```

my cert file name is bank...cert . but my problem don't solved and i can't add this service to wso2.

Comment: What is the exact error you have in your logs?  I am assuming you have restarted the wso2 service after you loaded the certificate?  Does your service address match the address the cert was issues to?

Comment: i have restarted wso2 service and export crt via firefox and import, do i should change ip address of web service to dns or name of certificate?

Comment: yes, make them match and let us know the results.

Comment: I did, and it works correctly, tanx